# Magento 2 : issue in database user privileges

Tags: magento2, database

I have moved my Magento 2 site files to another location and everything is working fine, but at the checkout page while doing the payment it is giving me the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 TRIGGER
>   command denied to user 'muellers_m2user'@'localhost' for table
>   'cataloginventory_stock_item', query was: UPDATE
>   `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN 197
>   THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (197)) AND (website_id =
>   0) this has product ID 197

The user "`muellers_m2user`" is the old username used in previous Magento 2 location as I have set up another user on a new location and defined in on `env.php` file.

So can anyone can let me know from where can I remove all the instance of old username in Magento 2?

Comment: Maybe you need to check database tables user access or owner of those tables.

Comment: how can I check the owner of the particular tables?

Comment: Try this :                                        SELECT 'db', User, Host
FROM db
WHERE Db='mydatabase'

UNION

SELECT 'table', User, Host
FROM tables_priv
WHERE Db='mydatabase'

UNION

SELECT 'col', User, Host
FROM columns_priv
WHERE Db='mydatabase'

Comment: @Echubnine did you find a solution to it?